# how to prevent tomcat from caching mysql data

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm not sure if this is a tomcat issue, or a mysql issue.  When reading an entire table (select * from Employees), and returning the data through jsp, the same data is returned even after updating the table.

I am using my own homespun connection pool.  That cant change at the moment as both a desktop app and the servlets use the same core libraries.

I have READ-COMMITTED set in mysql config

```
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
```

I even set it when creating the connection

```
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    if (conn != null)
        conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
```

Then in the servlet I get the data and send it out like this (GetAll() is effectively SELECT * from Employees):

```
Vector<DBO_Employees>vc = DBO_Employees.GetAll(); 
Vector<JSONObject>vr = new Vector<JSONObject>();
for (DBO_Employees h : vc)
    vr.add(h.json());
    try {
        json.put("employees", vr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8;");
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
pw.write(json.toString());
```

To test I call the servlet once, make a quick change in the database (using mysql cli), then refresh the page however the change in data is not there.  I'm not sure if mysql is caching the data or if tomcat is caching the data.

Comment: Or is your browser caching the data?  Try this - load the data once, change it in the DB, and load it again but the second time in an "incognito" or private window.  That should eliminate any browser caching issues.  Let us know if that helps.

Comment: i guess you should restart the server , but apparently in the latest tomcat version you don't need to !!

Comment: I tested the browser theory by using chrome and firefox.  grab the data, make a change in the db, switch to other browser and grab the data.  old data is still sent.  restart the server definately works, but that's kind of draconian to have to restart the server after every insert / update :)